# Gsutil does not work on gcloud, but localy works

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

Il'show you part of code. When i use in my python script, which get files from Firebase to download. Works everything fine

```
command  = '''gsutil -m cp -r gs://mk-dev.appspot.com/"Images/Project/XD03+400" ./download"'''

os.system(command)`
```

But when i upload this on gcp it doesnot work. There are no any errors in log.

My dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
ENV PORT 1234
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gsutil
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system 
CMD exec uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port ${PORT} --workers 1
```

and script to build image and run

```
#Config File for prepare deploy a code for Gloogle Cloud Build
function Get-MrPSVersion {
    $PSVersionTable
    $env:PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config list --format='value(core.project)')
    $env:PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe $env:PROJECT_ID --format='value(projectNumber)')
    Get-ChildItem env:
}

Get-MrPSVersion
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Output "Getting data"

Write-Output "creating docker."
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/$env:PROJECT_ID/devphoto

Write-Output "run docker"
gcloud run deploy devphoto --image gcr.io/$env:PROJECT_ID/devphoto:latest --region 'europe-west3' --platform managed
```

I'll make thousends of dockers and everythings works, but not gsutil

Any suggestion?

I'll make thousends of dockers and everythings works, but not gsutil

Comment: Which Google Cloud service are you using? What is the error? Have you checked Cloud Logging for warnings and errors? Edit your post and add more details. Tip: you are not capturing the output (stdout / stderr) from `os.command`. Do that so you know what error happens.

Comment: Also, read the system requirements and installation instructions. You are missing required packages: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#specifications